# Can someone tell me what this 5 petal pink flower is?

Tags: identification, perennials

5 petal perennial blooms in late May early June in zone 5.

[image: 1]

Comment: In US? "Zones" outside US/Canada have little use. Could you tell us about the size and may add photo of the plant (with leaves). 10 stamens, I would say Geranium.

Comment: Do you have any picture that shows the leaves?  Plants are actually easier to identify by leaf than by a single flower.  You need to give a detail description of the plant, if you do not have a better picture.    Without it my best guess would be some kind of perennial geranium.  Not the large red flowered annual, which is not actually a geranium.  A true geranium.   But, that is just a shot in the dark.  That is why I did not include under answer

Comment: +1 for good macro photo. Nice bocca. That's the background being out of focus to place attention on the subject.  But, yes, some leaves would help.

Answer (score 1):

It is Malva sylvestris. Wikipedia:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malva_sylvestris